# XSLT transformation setting namespace parameters for root element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming input XML to this output format:

```
<InvoiceTransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd">
  <InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
    <InvoiceCreationDate>2020-07-23</InvoiceCreationDate>
    <Version>2.0.2</Version>
  </InvoiceTransmissionHeader>
.....
</InvoiceTransmission>
```

And I have problem with proper setup of root element 
This is my XST but I am still receiving error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <!--<InvoiceTransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd">-->
        <InvoiceTransmission> 
        <xsl:element name="InvoiceTransmission"> 
            <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />           
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
                <xsl:value-of select="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SSC"/>
        </InvoiceTransmission>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is error which I receive:

```
XTDE0860  Undeclared namespace prefix {xsi}
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:namespace` statement produces a namespace node in the *output* - something which you probably do not need. In order to use the namespace in your XSL transformation, you must include an `xmlns:xsi` namespace declaration:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi" version="2.0">
```

Also, you probably want to replace

```xml
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
  <xsl:value-of select="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

with simply

```xml
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd</xsl:attribute>
```

because `IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd` is not a path in your XML document.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Now I have only one problem, in root element I have xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="" instead of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd"

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: `xmlns:xsi` is not an attribute; it's a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">        
    <InvoiceTransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="IATAFuelInvoiceStandardv2.0.2.xsd">
       <!--  the rest of the code -->
    </InvoiceTransmission>
</xsl:template>
```